# How to find local/epheremal port number?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, winsock, berkeley-sockets

I have a UDP client program that uses Berkley sockets and Winsock (depending on the platform).

Basically it uses `getaddrinfo()`, then `socket()`, then `sendto()`. `sendto()` takes the address info returned by `getaddrinfo()`. My code looks like this:

```
struct addrinfo hint;
memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
struct addrinfo *address;
getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "9999", &hint, &address);

SOCKET s = socket(address->ai_family, address->ai_socktype, address->ai_protocol);
sendto(s, "test", 4, 0, address->ai_addr, address->ai_addrlen);
```

My question is, when is the local/ephemeral port number set? Is it set with the call to `sendto()`? If I send more data to a different server, does `sendto()` reuse the same ephemeral port number? How can I get the ephemeral port number (in a protocol independent way)? I know that knowing this may not be useful, and NAT can change it anyway, but I'm just trying to understand how it all works better.

I also know I can use `bind()` to set the local port, but my question is about what happens when the OS chooses the local port for me.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `getsockname` function:

```
struct sockaddr_storage ss;
socklen_t len;

len = sizeof(ss);
if (getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr *)&ss, &len) == 0) {
    // print contents of ss
}
```

It populates the given `sockaddr` with the address and port that the socket is bound to.

This function is available in both winsock and Berkely sockets.

Comment: My question is, when is the local/ephemeral port number set? Is it set with the call to sendto()? If I send more data to a different server, does sendto() reuse the same ephemeral port number?

Comment: Also, your solution uses sockaddr_in, which will not work with IPv6. How can I make it work with addrinfo instead?

Comment: @mark Because a UDP socket is identified only by the source IP/port, the port is set on the first send.  As for `sockaddr_in`, I think you can use a `sockaddr_storage` instead to hold either an IPv4 or an IPv6 address, although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN's documentation for [`sendto()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-sendto) states:

> Note If a socket is opened, a `setsockopt` call is made, and then a `sendto` call is made, **Windows Sockets performs an implicit `bind` function call**.
>
> **If the socket is unbound, unique values are assigned to the local association by the system, and the socket is then marked as bound**. If the socket is connected, the `getsockname` function can be used to determine the local IP address and port associated with the socket.
>
> If the socket is not connected, the `getsockname` function can be used to determine the local port number associated with the socket but the IP address returned is set to the wildcard address for the given protocol (for example, `INADDR_ANY` or "0.0.0.0" for IPv4 and `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` or "::" for IPv6).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* `bind` to port *zero*  (`0`) which will cause OS to find an open ephemeral port that you can discover with `getsockname`, or return `EADDRINUSE`, *even before* you tried to send anything.

---

As for *when* an ephemeral port is allocated by the operating system, from [ip(7) Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html):

> [...]   An ephemeral port is allocated to a socket in the following 
>   circumstances:
>
> - the port number in a socket address is specified as 0 when
>      calling `bind(2)`;
> - `listen(2)` is called on a stream socket that was not previously bound;
> - `connect(2)` was called on a socket that was not previously
>      bound;
> - `sendto(2)` is called on a datagram socket that was not previously bound.